# How to add a choice field in JS Grid control

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, gridview

I need to add a choice field (dropdownlist) in each row of a JS Grid control. What is the PropertyID for a choice field. How to add a dropdown. Please assist.

i tried like this,but this didnt work

else if (dc.DataType == typeof(Enum))

```
            {
                gf.PropertyTypeId = "Enum";

                gf.Localizer = (ValueLocalizer)delegate(DataRow row, object toConvert)
                {
                    return toConvert == null ? "" : toConvert.ToString();
                };

                gf.SerializeLocalizedValue = false;

                gf.SerializeDataValue = true;

            }
```

Please provide the solution

Thanks in advance !